# I'm having trouble defining a new command

Tags: macros

so what I want to do is make commands that makes mm, in regular font in my equations. So before `\begin{document}` I have put `\newcommand{cm}{\text{cm}}` and then it comes up as `Latex Error: No \begin{document}`. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Commands begin with a backslash: `\newcommand{\cm}{\text{cm}}`

Comment: Could you please edit your question and clarify what exactly you wanted to achieve with this macro. I failed to understand what you are asking for. Anyway, to define a new command you need to write in the syntax `\newcommand{cmd}[args]{def}`, where cmd _must_ be a command name beginning with a \. So, at least you can put a \ before cm in `\newcommand{cm}`.

Comment: You may want to look at the `siunitx` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

Well, trying to give a complete answer:

1. The correct syntax, as described by MMA is:

   ```
   \newcommand{<commandname>}[<arguments>]{<definition>}`
   ```

   Please note that the `<commandname>` must start with `\`.  Example:

   ```
   \newcommand{\acro}[1]{{\normalfont\slshape #1\/}}
   ```
2. Since what it seems you are trying to use is units, you should check
   the [`siunitx` package](http://www.http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), as described by egreg.

   The syntax while using the `siunitx` package is: `\SI{quantity}{unit}`.  For example `\SI{3.14}{\metre}`